# A query executed in a backup of a database is performing better than if executed in the original database

Tags: oracle, performance, execution-plan

We have two databases with the same data, let's call it Database A which is the original and Database B which is the backup from Database A. A query is performing much better in Database B for example the query takes 42 ms and in Database A takes 10 seconds. I noticed that the execution plans are different. I already asked the DBA of the company but he has no clue what could the problem be. There are 42 entries in the execution plan of Database A and only 33 entries in Database A, maybe that could be the problem but I don't know.

**UPDATE**:
I've been researching and I found out that this has something to do with hash join. Database A is performing hash join on **VW_PERSONA** while Database B is performing NESTED JOIN. The end result is that HASH JOIN for this case performs bad. What could be the reason that Database A prefers HASH JOIN instead of NESTED LOOPS JOIN? I verified this by forcing a HASH JOIN using a hint in Database B and it performed as bad as Database A.

**Version of the Database:**
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

This is the query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.CLAVEESTATUS, t1.IDEJECUTIVO, t1.GERENCIA_ID, t1.IDTIPOEJECUTIVO, t1.IDDOMICILIO, t1.IDPERSONA, t0.ID, t0.CLAVEESTATUS, t0.CORREOELECTRONICO, t0.DESCRIPCION, t0.IDGERENCIA, t0.CENTROOPERACION_ID, t0.IDDOMICILIO, t0.IDPERSONARESPONSABLE, t2.BCATPURAASEG, t2.CALLENUMERO, t2.CIUDAD, t2.CLAVECIUDAD, t2.CLAVEESTADO, t2.CLAVEPAIS, t2.CLAVEUSUARIOMODIFICACION, t2.CODIGOPOSTAL, t2.ESTADO, t2.FECHAMODIFICACION, t2.IDCOLONIA, t2.idPersona, t2.COLONIA, t2.TIPODOMICILIO, t2.idDomicilio, t3.IDPERSONA, t3.APELLIDOMATERNO, t3.APELLIDOPATERNO, t3.BCAPTURAASEG, t3.CLAVEESTADOCIVIL, t3.CLAVEESTADONACIMIENTO, t3.CLAVEMUNICIPIONACIMIENTO, t3.CLAVENACIONALIDAD, t3.CLAVERAMAACTIV, t3.CLAVERAMAPERSONAFISICA, t3.CLAVERESIDENCIA, t3.CLAVESEXO, t3.CLAVESITUACION, t3.CLAVESUBRAMAACTIV, t3.CLAVETIPOPERSONA, t3.CLAVETIPOSECTOR, t3.CLAVETIPOSECTORMORAL, t3.CLAVETIPOSITUACION, t3.CLAVEUSUARIOMODIFICACION, t3.CORREOSADICIONALES, t3.CURP, t3.EMAIL, t3.FACEBOOK, t3.FECHAALTA, t3.FECHABAJA, t3.FECHACONSTITUCION, t3.FECHAMODIFICACION, t3.FECHANACIMIENTO, t3.IDREPRESENTANTE, t3.LUGARNACIMIENTO, t3.NOMBRE, t3.NOMBRECOMPLETO, t3.NOMBRECONTACTO, t3.PAGINAWEB, t3.PUESTOCONTACTO, t3.RAZONSOCIAL, t3.CODIGORFC, t3.TELEFONOCASA, t3.TELEFONOCELULAR, t3.TELEFONOFAX, t3.TELEFONOOFICINA, t3.TELEFONOSADICIONALES, t3.TWITTER 
    FROM MIDAS.TOEJECUTIVO t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MIDAS.TOGERENCIA t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.GERENCIA_ID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MIDAS.VW_DOMICILIO t2 ON ((t2.idDomicilio = t1.IDDOMICILIO) AND (t2.idPersona = t1.IDPERSONA)) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MIDAS.VW_PERSONA t3 ON (t3.IDPERSONA = t1.IDPERSONA);
```

The execution plans for that query:

**Database A (performs bad, takes 10 seconds):**

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 1113260721

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                     |    79 |   108K|       |   996K  (1)| 03:19:14 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER                      |                     |    79 |   108K|       |   996K  (1)| 03:19:14 |
|   2 |   VIEW                                |                     |    79 | 40290 |       |   659  (13)| 00:00:08 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                 |                     |    79 | 43687 |       |   659  (13)| 00:00:08 |
|   4 |     VIEW                              |                     |    79 | 22199 |       |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                  |                     |    79 |  5925 |       |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TOEJECUTIVO         |    79 |  1343 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TOGERENCIA          |    31 |  1798 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE             |                     |     1 |   272 |       |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |      WINDOW SORT                      |                     |     1 |   195 |       |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                     |     1 |   195 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                     |     1 |   156 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                     |     1 |   126 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | DOMICILIO           |     1 |    96 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX01_DOMICILIO_PER |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | POBLACION           |     1 |    30 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_POBLACION        |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | POBLACION           |     1 |    30 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_POBLACION        |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CODIGO_POSTAL       |     1 |    39 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | PK_CODIGO_POSTAL    |     5 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |   VIEW                                | VW_PERSONA          |   917K|   782M|       |   995K  (1)| 03:19:06 |
|  22 |    MERGE JOIN OUTER                   |                     |   917K|   803M|       |   995K  (1)| 03:19:06 |
|  23 |     VIEW                              |                     |   917K|   787M|       |   760K  (1)| 02:32:05 |
|  24 |      MERGE JOIN OUTER                 |                     |   917K|   734M|       |   760K  (1)| 02:32:05 |
|  25 |       VIEW                            |                     |   917K|   691M|       |   531K  (1)| 01:46:13 |
|  26 |        MERGE JOIN OUTER               |                     |   917K|   631M|       |   531K  (1)| 01:46:13 |
|  27 |         VIEW                          |                     |   917K|   584M|       |   508K  (1)| 01:41:47 |
|  28 |          MERGE JOIN OUTER             |                     |   917K|    91M|       |   508K  (1)| 01:41:47 |
|  29 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PERSONA             |   917K|    75M|       |   258K  (1)| 00:51:41 |
|  30 |            INDEX FULL SCAN            | PK_PERSONA          |   917K|       |       |  1546   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|* 31 |           SORT JOIN                   |                     |   916K|    16M|    84M|   250K  (1)| 00:50:06 |
|  32 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PERSONA_EXT         |   916K|    16M|       |   245K  (1)| 00:49:01 |
|  33 |             INDEX FULL SCAN           | PK_PERSONA_EXT      |   916K|       |       |  1959   (1)| 00:00:24 |
|* 34 |         SORT JOIN                     |                     | 73382 |  3869K|    10M| 22109   (1)| 00:04:26 |
|  35 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PERSONA_MORAL       | 73382 |  3869K|       | 21130   (1)| 00:04:14 |
|  36 |           INDEX FULL SCAN             | PK_PERSONA_MORAL    | 73382 |       |       |   129   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|* 37 |       SORT JOIN                       |                     |   843K|    39M|   129M|   229K  (1)| 00:45:53 |
|  38 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | PERSONA_FISICA      |   843K|    39M|       |   219K  (1)| 00:43:49 |
|  39 |         INDEX FULL SCAN               | PK_PERSONA_FISICA   |   843K|       |       |  1633   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|* 40 |     SORT JOIN                         |                     |   760K|    13M|    46M|   235K  (1)| 00:47:02 |
|  41 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | RFC                 |   760K|    13M|       |   230K  (1)| 00:46:10 |
|  42 |       INDEX FULL SCAN                 | PK_RFC              |   760K|       |       |  1558   (1)| 00:00:19 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("T3"."IDPERSONA"(+)="T1"."IDPERSONA")
   5 - access("T0"."ID"(+)="T1"."GERENCIA_ID")
   8 - filter("ID_DOMICILIO"(+)="T1"."IDDOMICILIO" AND "CUENTA"(+)="NUMERO"(+))
  14 - access("DOM"."ID_PERSONA"="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("ID_PERSONA" IS NOT NULL)
  15 - filter("POBLACION"."CVE_TIPO_POBLAC"='ES' AND "POBLACION"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "POBLACION"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC"="DOM"."CVE_PAIS")
  16 - access("POBLACION"."CVE_POBLACION"="DOM"."CVE_ESTADO")
  17 - filter("CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC" IS NOT NULL AND "CIUDAD"."CVE_TIPO_POBLAC"='CD' AND 
              "CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC"="DOM"."CVE_ESTADO")
  18 - access("CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLACION"="DOM"."CVE_CIUDAD")
  19 - filter("DOM"."COLONIA"="CP"."DESC_USR_CODPOST"(+))
  20 - access("DOM"."CODIGO_POSTAL"="CP"."CODIGO_POSTAL"(+))
  31 - access("PEXT"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
       filter("PEXT"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  34 - access("MORAL"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
       filter("MORAL"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  37 - access("FISICA"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
       filter("FISICA"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  40 - access("RFC"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
       filter("RFC"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
```

**Database B execution plan (performs better, takes 42 ms):**

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 2434982697

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                     |  1522 |  1863K|  1271   (7)| 00:00:16 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                 |                     |  1522 |  1863K|  1271   (7)| 00:00:16 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                     |    79 | 77578 |   619   (1)| 00:00:08 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                | TOGERENCIA          |    31 |  1953 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                     |    79 | 72601 |   616   (1)| 00:00:08 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TOEJECUTIVO         |    79 |  1738 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE           | VW_PERSONA          |     1 |   897 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                     |     1 |   260 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                     |     1 |   232 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                     |     1 |   175 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                     |     1 |   118 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PERSONA             |     1 |    98 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_PERSONA          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RFC                 |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_RFC              |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PERSONA_FISICA      |     1 |    57 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_PERSONA_FISICA   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PERSONA_MORAL       |     1 |    57 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_PERSONA_MORAL    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PERSONA_EXT         |     1 |    28 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_PERSONA_EXT      |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE             |                     |     1 |   272 |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |    WINDOW SORT                      |                     |     1 |   195 |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                     |     1 |   195 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |      NESTED LOOPS                   |                     |     1 |   156 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |       NESTED LOOPS                  |                     |     1 |   126 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | DOMICILIO           |     1 |    96 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX01_DOMICILIO_PER |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | POBLACION           |     1 |    30 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_POBLACION        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | POBLACION           |     1 |    30 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_POBLACION        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CODIGO_POSTAL       |     1 |    39 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN              | PK_CODIGO_POSTAL    |     5 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("T0"."ID"(+)="T1"."GERENCIA_ID")
  12 - access("P"."ID_PERSONA"="T1"."IDPERSONA")
  14 - access("RFC"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("RFC"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  16 - access("FISICA"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("FISICA"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  18 - access("MORAL"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("MORAL"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  20 - access("PEXT"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("PEXT"."ID_PERSONA"(+)="P"."ID_PERSONA")
  21 - filter("ID_DOMICILIO"(+)="T1"."IDDOMICILIO" AND "CUENTA"(+)="NUMERO"(+))
  27 - access("DOM"."ID_PERSONA"="T1"."IDPERSONA")
       filter("ID_PERSONA" IS NOT NULL)
  28 - filter("POBLACION"."CVE_TIPO_POBLAC"='ES' AND "POBLACION"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "POBLACION"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC"="DOM"."CVE_PAIS")
  29 - access("POBLACION"."CVE_POBLACION"="DOM"."CVE_ESTADO")
  30 - filter("CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC" IS NOT NULL AND "CIUDAD"."CVE_TIPO_POBLAC"='CD' AND 
              "CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLAC_UBIC"="DOM"."CVE_ESTADO")
  31 - access("CIUDAD"."CVE_POBLACION"="DOM"."CVE_CIUDAD")
  32 - filter("DOM"."COLONIA"="CP"."DESC_USR_CODPOST"(+))
  33 - access("DOM"."CODIGO_POSTAL"="CP"."CODIGO_POSTAL"(+))
```

**VW_PERSONA (VIEW):**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MIDAS.VW_PERSONA
(
   IDPERSONA,
   IDDOMICILIO,
   CLAVERESIDENCIA,
   CLAVENACIONALIDAD,
   CLAVETIPOPERSONA,
   FECHAALTA,
   FECHABAJA,
   CLAVETIPOSITUACION,
   TELEFONOCASA,
   TELEFONOFAX,
   TELEFONOOFICINA,
   CLAVETIPOSECTOR,
   NOMBRECOMPLETO,
   FECHAMODIFICACION,
   CLAVEUSUARIOMODIFICACION,
   BCAPTURAASEG,
   EMAIL,
   CURP,
   TELEFONOCELULAR,
   NOMBRECONTACTO,
   PUESTOCONTACTO,
   FACEBOOK,
   TWITTER,
   PAGINAWEB,
   TELEFONOSADICIONALES,
   CORREOSADICIONALES,
   IDREPRESENTANTE,
   RAZONSOCIAL,
   FECHACONSTITUCION,
   CLAVERAMAACTIV,
   CLAVESUBRAMAACTIV,
   CLAVETIPOSECTORMORAL,
   NOMBRE,
   APELLIDOPATERNO,
   APELLIDOMATERNO,
   CLAVESITUACION,
   CLAVEESTADOCIVIL,
   CLAVERAMAPERSONAFISICA,
   CLAVESEXO,
   FECHANACIMIENTO,
   LUGARNACIMIENTO,
   CLAVEESTADONACIMIENTO,
   CLAVEMUNICIPIONACIMIENTO,
   CODIGORFC,
   SIGLASRFC,
   FECHARFC,
   HOMOCLAVERFC
)
AS
   SELECT /*+ INDEX(pext PK_PERSONA_EXT) INDEX(p PK_PERSONA) INDEX(fisica PK_PERSONA_FISICA) INDEX(moral PK_PERSONA_MORAL) INDEX(rfc PK_RFC)*/
         p  .id_persona AS idPersona,
            p.id_domicilio AS idDomicilio,
            p.cve_residencia AS claveResidencia,
            p.cve_nacionalidad AS claveNacionalidad,
            CASE WHEN p.cve_per_juridica = 'PF' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
               AS claveTipoPersona,
            p.f_alta AS fechaAlta,
            p.f_baja AS fechaBaja,
            p.sit_persona AS claveTipoSituacion,
            p.telef_casa AS telefonoCasa,
            p.telef_fax AS telefonoFax,
            p.telef_oficina AS telefonoOficina,
            p.cve_tipo_sector AS claveTipoSector,
            p.nombre AS nombreCompleto,
            p.fh_modificacion AS fechaModificacion,
            p.cve_usuar_modif AS claveUsuarioModificacion,
            p.b_captura_aseg AS bCapturaAseg,
            --          pext.e_mail AS email,
            --          trim(TRANSLATE(pext.e_mail,'áéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôôäëïöüçÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÕÂÊÎÔÛÄËÏÖÜÇ','aeiouaeiouaoaeiooaeioucAEIOUAEIOUAOAEIOOAEIOUC'))  email,
            TRIM (pext.e_mail) email,
            pext.curp AS curp,
            pext.telef_celular AS telefonoCelular,
            pext.nombre_contacto AS nombreContacto,
            pext.puesto_contacto AS puestoContacto,
            pext.facebook,
            pext.twitter,
            pext.pagina_web AS paginaWeb,
            pext.tels_adicionales AS telefonosAdicionales,
            pext.correos_adicionales AS correosAdicionales,
            pext.id_representante AS idRepresentante,
            moral.nom_razon_social AS razonSocial,
            moral.f_constitucion AS fechaConstitucion,
            moral.cve_rama_activ AS claveRamaActiv,
            moral.cve_sub_rama_ac AS claveSubramaActiv,
            moral.cve_tipo_sector AS claveTipoSectorMoral,
            fisica.nombre_persona AS nombre,
            fisica.apellido_paterno AS apellidoPaterno,
            fisica.apellido_materno AS apellidoMaterno,
            fisica.cve_actividad_pf AS claveSituacion,
            fisica.cve_estado_civil AS claveEstadoCivil,
            fisica.cve_rama_pf AS claveRamaPersonaFisica,
            fisica.cve_sexo AS claveSexo,
            fisica.f_nacimiento AS fechaNacimiento,
            fisica.lugar_nacim AS lugarNacimiento,
            fisica.cve_estado_nacim AS claveEstadoNacimiento,
            fisica.cve_munic_nacim AS claveMunicipioNacimiento,
            rfc.siglas_rfc || rfc.f_rfc || rfc.homoclave_rfc AS codigoRfc,
            rfc.siglas_rfc AS siglasRfc,
            rfc.f_rfc AS fechaRfc,
            rfc.homoclave_rfc AS homoclaveRfc
     FROM               SEYCOS.persona p
                     LEFT JOIN
                        SEYCOS.persona_ext pext
                     ON (pext.id_persona = p.id_persona)
                  LEFT JOIN
                     SEYCOS.persona_moral moral
                  ON (moral.id_persona = p.id_persona)
               LEFT JOIN
                  SEYCOS.persona_fisica fisica
               ON (fisica.id_persona = p.id_persona)
            LEFT JOIN
               SEYCOS.RFC rfc
            ON (rfc.id_persona = p.id_persona);
```

Comment: Are statistics up to date on A? Are there any differences in settings (including system statistics) and hardware between the two instances?

Comment: @Colin'tHart According to the DBA statistics are up to date. There are no differences in the configuration between the two databases.

Comment: The explains plan are really different. there are based on the statistics. You may compare it using user_tables, user_tab_columns, user_indexes.

Comment: What kind of backup? Made by rman/datafile copies/snapshots or made by exports/imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for a while, the problem was that a parameter was different between the two databases. Database A had **_complex_view_merging** set to **FALSE** and Database B didn't have it. I just changed **_complex_view_merging** to **TRUE** in Database A and the query executed as quickly as Database B.